# Кэширование частообновляемой базы

Tags: php, mysql

Имеется база из 6000 элементов(и это не предел), в ней 35 полей из которых половина обновляется чуть ли не каждые 5 минут(а у некоторых записей и то чаще). Из-за частоты обновления данных, строки при обновлении берутся по 100шт. Индексы расставлены на поля по которым происходит сортировка и выборка.

1. Имеет ли смысл включать для такой базы кэширование?
2. Имеет ли смысл выносить частообновляемые поля в отдельную таблицу? (сюда же) На страницах товаров, почти все поля используются, надо ли делать 2 базы вместо 1?
3. Handler read rnd next почему то увеличивается на 1,5к только при обновлении страницы, когда я на него смотрю через PMA; если же вернуться посмотреть через время, то увеличение будет уже не значительное(наверное с учетом тех 1,5к при обновлении). Значит ли это что запросы оптимизировались?

Comment: Размер такой таблицы - несколько мегабайт, она и так вся в памяти лежит. Обновление раз в 5 минут - это очень редко. Как на таком материале получить тормоза - загадка...

Comment: Ну видать примитивно звучит с моих слов, но таблица весит 200 МБ. Забыл упомянуть, 3 из постоянно обновляемых полей - текстовые. В них тоже информация в base64. За пять минут обновляются все 6к записей. Если бы была возможность проходить такое количество за меньшее время то скорее бы так и было... База в InnoDB.